# NBBO execution at public exchange

Tags: stock-exchanges, sec, nasdaq, order-execution, nyse

There are about 16 stock exchanges in the U.S market. According to Reg NMS, broker-dealers have to guarantee at least NBBO price to its customer. My question is if the best ask is coming from say IEX and the broker I am using is not a member to IEX, can my broker still route my order to IEX assuming that my broker is not routing my order to market maker and other brokers and only executing my order at public exchanges.